# How can I create Mapbox vector tiles with zoom extent 0-4?

Tags: convert, mapbox, vector-tiles

when I use Mapbox and load a vector polygon.
after upload is done the file is converted to vector tiles.
it is then assigned a zoom extent:
[image]

How can I tweak this ? I would like the tiles created from this polygon to be available between zoom 0 and 4 and not 4 to 10.

It doesn't work when I try to override the zoom extent visibility from the style.

Comment: I'd actually like an answer to this. Did your answer below allow you to use your sources in Mapbox Studio? Or did you have to use 'Studio Classic'? Otherwise, I'd like to know how it determines the zoom extents (the 4-10 shown above above) and why you can't modify this value. Anyone have an answer?

Comment: AFAIK these values can only be set from **Mapbox studio classic**. and I do not know how Mapbox studio determines its defaults..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Mapbox's [Tileset Errors](https://www.mapbox.com/help/large-data-tippecanoe/) documentation, [Tippecanoe](https://www.mapbox.com/help/tileset-errors/) is the recommended way to process detailed tile layers for viewing at arbitrary zoom levels. In addition to creating extremely efficient tile layers, its advantage over Mapbox Studio Classic is that as a command-line utility it can be incorporated into scripts. There's even an existing Python binding called togeojsontiles. Tippecanoe is natively supported on Linux and OS X, but it's also possible to run it from Windows using Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

found the solution in the documentation:
[mapbox documentation page regarding uploads](https://www.mapbox.com/help/uploads/)

> ...When uploading through Mapbox Studio Classic source mode, you can manually determine maximum and minimum zoom levels for the dataset...